# Convert char array to int array with spaces

Tags: java

I have browsed all over for this.I have a char array[10 20 30].I want to convert this to an int array or ArrayList of integers such that my int array become
int[] charToInt={10,20,30};
I need the initial guidance to approach this problem.I don't want the whole code.Just a hint.And I will code that hint.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand. Do you mean you have a char array `{'1', '0', ' ', '2', '0', ...}`? and you mean you want to convert that to an int array `{10, 20, ...}`?

Comment: @Radiodef: Yes that is right

Comment: yup it is an "or" sorry

Comment: Please elaborate on `char array[10 20 30]`.

Comment: Is your char array really a char array or do you actually have a String `"10 20 30"`? (Raw char arrays are very uncommon in Java.) You should edit the question to clarify this stuff.

Comment: this is a char array.I am reading this from file and want to perform some arithmetic operation on numbers only.That is the reason I want to convert this from char to integer

Comment: @Shehlina edit your question to include the code you've got so far and include contents of the file you're reading in.

Comment: char array[10 20 30] feels very ambiguous  can you elaborate more?
what is in yourarray[0] ?

Comment: @luisluix Shehlina's response to Radiodef indicates that she means that the array is `{'1', '0', ' ', '2', '0' , ' ' , '3', '0'}`, not `{(char)10, (char)20, (char)30}`.  This should probably be in the body of the question, as well as the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated:** Here is working example

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Example {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[] input = { '1', '0',  ' ', '2', '0', ' ', '3', '0'};
    ArrayList<Integer> output = extractIntegers(input);

    for (int i : output) {
      System.out.println(i);
    }
  }

  private static ArrayList<Integer> extractIntegers(char[] chars) {
    int start = -1;
    ArrayList<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
      boolean isDigit = Character.isDigit(chars[i]);
      if (start != -1 && !isDigit) {
        integers.add(parseInt(chars, start, i));
        start = -1;
      } else if (start == -1 && isDigit) {
        start = i;
      }
    }
    if (start != -1) {
      integers.add(parseInt(chars, start, chars.length));
    }
    return integers;
  }

  private static int parseInt(char[] chars, int start, int stop) {
    return Integer.parseInt(new String(chars, start, stop - start));
  }
}
```

1. Save this code in a file called `Example.java`
2. Compile it `$ javac Example.java`
3. Run it `$ java Example`

Comment: Please edit your answer into include the code you've got so far and include the contents of the input file.

Comment: @PeterSutton 1.Asks about char array 2.You do not check about non-numeric string values, converting a String to int may throw an exception

Comment: @sotcha 1) it's not clear what is asking about. I put this here as a best guess that I'm working on now. 2) Good, it should throw an exception. If you don't know how an exception should be handled, you let the exception propagate.

Comment: I've updated my answer to my current best guess of what you're looking for.

Comment: My code does not handle signed numbers. This is only a problem if you need to handle signed numbers.

Answer (score 1):

A way to convert a `char` array with the structure `{'number', ' ', 'number', ' ', ... }` to an `int` array would be:

```
public static int[] toIntArray(final char[] source) {
    if (source == null || source.length == 0) { // check for null or empty array
        return new int[0];
    }

    final String sourceAsStr = String.copyValueOf(source); // convert array to string
    final String[] numbers = sourceAsStr.split(" "); // split string on "space"; each part contains a number
    final int[] result = new int[numbers.length];

    for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        try {
            result[i] = Integer.parseInt(numbers[i]);
        } catch (final NumberFormatException e) {
            // handle exception
            return new int[0]; // return empty array on exception
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Example:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(toIntArray(new char[] {'1', '0', ' ', '2', '0', ' ', '3', '0'})));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(toIntArray(new char[] {'1', '0', '-', '2', '0', '-', '3', '0'})));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(toIntArray(null)));
```

Result:

```
[10, 20, 30]
[]
[]
```

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at String.split:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

and Integer.parseInt:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)

Comment: As you may already know: link only answers are not really "good" and should be a comment instead.

Comment: @Tom Or really just elaborated upon.